# Dual boot (Win 7 & Ubuntu 13.10 clock problem

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a "newbie" to Ubuntu, but I've been wrestling with this problem for several hours and don't seem to be able to solve it: When I set the time in Windows (Indianapolis, Eastern U.S. time zone) and then re-boot to Ubuntu, the computer time goes to Hawaiian time.
When the time is set in Ubuntu, and the computer is rebooted to Windows the time is advanced by 5 hours.

I've set the time in the BIOS, and it seems to make no difference. I've tried setting the time from "automatic" to "manual", all with the same result.
Not a big problem, but it shows some underlying glitch.
Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 6):

It is because Linux stores time as UTC and windows as Local.

You can make Linux use local time or Windows use UTC.

To make Linux use local time edit /etc/default/rcS and change UTC=yes to UTC=no

To make Windows use UTC, create a new file named UTC.reg with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

and open it with regedit in windows.

Comment: Although you should probably avoid UTC on windows. It does some weird stuff. I'd post some links but i can't remember where i saw all those issues windows had with utc.