# Synchronize time in Ubuntu desktop

Tags: time

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Each time when I log into Windows I find that time is invalid. When set it Ubuntu time crashed. What do to fix it?

Comment: When you change the time in Ubuntu, the time crash or? Give us more information pleas.

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/375492/dual-boot-win-7-ubuntu-13-10-clock-problem/375551#375551

Comment: for example i set time for tehran,iran in ubuntu,when i log into windows i saw that the is diffrente

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your [CMOS battery](https://www.google.com.cy/search?q=bios+battery&client=ubuntu-browser&es_sm=114&tbm=isch&imgil=Et7gb-nVhJye-M%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcSprNERGzK_C1_NgSulmnARJqBpHBT-mxzVUbdpgfpbuQi8J-RM%253B658%253B403%253Bge-3LOTBHB3PHM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fpctechnotes.com%25252Fhow-to-change-your-cmos-battery%25252F&source=iu&usg=__BK_O6vZNJSOMdWG62M6EFLqpM8A%3D&sa=X&ei=9syEU5WmB4Gu0QXS4YCwDg&ved=0CDMQ9QEwAg#q=CMOS+battery&tbm=isch).